# Change Layout Design of A Drag and Drop Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to use a drag and drop feature using `jQuery` and found the below a useful one. So here how it works:

```js
 $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
```

```css
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

So pretty basic, just require to drag and drop from one list to another. Now what I am trying to do, is as follows:

```
Box 1   Item 1
Box 2   Item 2
Box 3   Item 3
Box 4   Item 4
```

On the left, there will be four empty boxes and in the right, items. So when I'll drag an item from right to left, it should fit into any of the boxes and in the same way, it can be dragged back to the right section. I was expecting if it could be done in the plugin and done ending something like this, though it creates empty boxes but unable to fit them into empty boxes: (The number of empty boxes will be equal to no of items)

```js
 $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
 }).disableSelection();
```

```css
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"></li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to make it work with the `jQuery` plugin?

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/PZrLHKH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid jQuery UI's sortable is not well suited to accomplish that task. A much better choice would be to leverage both [Draggable](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) jQuery UI widgets.

I'm attaching a working code snippet. You'd have to polish the behaviour, adjust the styles and put some real content (random content right now).

Should you need to make the panel items sortable as well, that'd be achievable too, although it would require a bit more code.

```js
/* global $ */

$(function () {
  var $mainSection = $('#main');
  var $leftPanelTargets = $('#left-panel > .item-container');
  var $rightPanelTargets = $('#right-panel > .item-container');

  // Populate the leftPanel with sample items
  $leftPanelTargets.each(function addItem(i, container) {
    const $item = $('<div class="drag-item"></div>');
    $item.append(`<h5 class="ui-widget-header">Title ${i + 1}</h5>`);
    $item.append('<div class="sample-image"></div>');
    $(container).append($item);
  });
  
  // Make all drag items draggable
  $('.drag-item', $mainSection).draggable({
    revert: 'invalid', // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
    containment: 'document',
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
  });

  // Let the rightPanel containers (targets) be droppable, accepting items from the leftPanel
  $rightPanelTargets.droppable({
    accept: '#left-panel > .item-container > .drag-item',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      dropImageRight(ui.draggable, event.target);
    },
  });

  // Let the leftPanel containers be droppable as well, accepting items from the rightPanel
  $leftPanelTargets.droppable({
    accept: '#right-panel > .item-container > .drag-item',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      dropImageLeft(ui.draggable, event.target);
    },
  });

  // Move a draggable item from the leftPanel to the rightPanel
  function dropImageRight($item, target) {
    $item.fadeOut(function () {
      $item.appendTo(target).fadeIn();
    });
  }

  // Move a draggable item from the rightPanel to the leftPanel
  function dropImageLeft($item, target) {
    $item.fadeOut(function () {
      $item.appendTo(target).fadeIn();
    });
  }

});
```

```css
#main * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#left-panel {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
}

#right-panel {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
}

#left-panel h4,
#right-panel h4 {
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 0 0 0.4em;
}

.item-container.ui-droppable-active:empty {
  background: #efe7ff;
}

.item-container.ui-droppable-active.ui-droppable-hover:empty {
  background: #d0bcfa;
}

.item-list > div {
  width: 112px;
  height: 112px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  margin: 0 0.4em 0.4em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-list > div h5 {
  margin: 0 0 0.4em;
  cursor: move;
}

.item-list > div img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: move;
}

.item-container {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.sample-image {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<section id="main" class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">

    <div id="left-panel" class="item-list">
        <div class="item-container"></div>  
        <div class="item-container"></div>
        <div class="item-container"></div>
        <div class="item-container"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="right-panel" class="item-list">
        <div class="item-container"></div>
        <div class="item-container"></div>
        <div class="item-container"></div>
        <div class="item-container"></div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Your solution is just perfect @Alex Tymchuk. Thanks a lot and really appreciate it. Though I may ask for a favor, if you could help me to provide the sorting feature as well specifically for the empty boxes, so I can sort them in the same area and I am actually not that efficient with `jQuery`.

Comment: @user8512043 I guess it should be a different question, if I interpret correctly the stackoverflow rule that says "[Your questions should be reasonably scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". I can only suggest that to achieve sorting for the empty boxes you'd need to `broaden` the accept filter, i.e. something like `accept: '.item-container > .drag-item'`.

Comment: OK @Alex Tymchuk. I am posting it in a different thread and tried something to make it work. See if you can check that out.